# super statement in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I'm creating a class to manage exception in c#, and I'd like to create some constructor methods which recalls the superclass; this is the definition of my class:

```
class DataSourceNotFoundException: System.Exception
```

but since in c# there is no super method what am I supposed to call to get the constructor methods of `System.Exception`?

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but the "exception" snippet in Visual Studio is very helpful, it generates some constructors (4) that call the base ctor, plus the ctor for serialization support.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You call a parent constructor using `base` *before* the body of the constructor:

```
public class FooException : Exception
{
    public FooException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}
```

Obviously you don't *have* to just pass a parameter from your own constructor up as an argument to the base constructor:

```
public class FooException : Exception
{
    public FooException(int x) : base("Hello")
    {
        // Do something with x
    }
}
```

The equivalent to chain to a constructor in the current class is to use `this` instead of `base`.

Note that constructor chaining works *very* slightly differently in C# compared with Java, with respect to when instance variable initializers are run. See my [article on C# constructors](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/constructors.html) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

In general the keyword `base` is what you want. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
class DataSourceNotFoundException: System.Exception {
    public DataSourceNotFoundException()
        : base()
    {
        //some code
    }

    public DataSourceNotFoundException(string message, object other)
        : base(message)
    {
        //some code
    }
```